# Relationship between lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have two lists, I want to sort the first one so I get them in ascending order, but I need the second list elements to be sorted with the element of the other list which they originally corresponded and I have no clue how to do that. Example:

```
Original imput:
l1 = [13, 1, 31, 6, 42, 99]
l2 = [14, 5, 11 ,7, 15, 12]

l1.sort()

Expected Result:
l1 = [1, 6, 13, 31, 42, 99]
l2 = [5, 7, 14 ,11, 15, 12]
```

Comment: did you try any code please upload that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack them in a tuple and sort it, then unpack as needed:

```py
t = tuple(zip(l1, l2))
l_sorted = sorted(t, key=lambda e: e[0])
l1 = [e[0] for e in l_sorted]
l2 = [e[1] for e in l_sorted]
```

Comment: Can I use this method for multiple lists at a time? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sure, any number of lists!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted`.

```
def sort_list(list1, list2):
 
    zipped_pairs = zip(list2, list1)
    j=sorted(zipped_pairs)
    z = [x for _, x in j]
    m = [__ for __, y in j]
    print(z,m)
l1 = [13, 1, 31, 6, 42, 99]
l2 = [14, 5, 11 ,7, 15, 12]
print(sort_list(l1, l2))
```

Comment: I´ll try this and see if I can use it for my code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Its faster if you can use numpy arrays. For example

```py
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([13, 1, 31, 6, 42, 99])
arr2 = np.array([14, 5, 11 ,7, 15, 12])

arr1_sorted = np.sort(arr1)
arr2_sorted = arr2[arr1.argsort()]

# The expected answer would be
# arr1_sorted = array([1, 6, 13, 31, 42, 99])
# arr2_sorted = array([5, 7, 14 ,11, 15, 12])
```

Here `sort()` returns the sorted array, while `argsort()` returns the index corresponding to a sorted array

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely to be fastest solution, but beautiful to my eye :)

```
l1 = [13, 1, 31, 6, 42, 99]
l2 = [14, 5, 11 ,7, 15, 12]

def delegated_sort(l1, l2):
  return map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2))))
```

```
>>> delegated_sort(l1, l2)
[[1, 6, 13, 31, 42, 99], [5, 7, 14, 11, 15, 12]]`
```